# Service Fabric Actor interface inheritance

Tags: c#, interface, actor, azure-service-fabric

I have an 'Common' interface I1 that defines some behavior behavior, e.g.:

```
interface I1
{
   Task<int> Calculate(int intput);
}
```

I'd like to inherit this interface from multiple actor interfaces, so they can implement it in various ways:

```
interface IActor1 : I1, IActor
{

}

interface IActor2: I1, IActor
{

}
```

However when compiling, it's failing (with no indication that it's caused by the interface inheritance). Seems like any actor interface anywhere in inheritance hierarchy has to implement IActor

Why is that, does seem to add any benefit, it only clutters my 'Common' library (where I1 is defined) with Actor specific dependecies that the consumers don't care about

Any idea how to achieve this?

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Thx for the answer Eli. What's thje point of it - iit seems against everything we believe in modern programming. As far as I can see completely useless restriction and should be removed

Comment: It seems to me that that the only way an interface can be determine to be managed by SF is via the IActor interface, which itself inherits from many other interfaces.  If you cast to I1, how will SF know that it's a managed interface for SF?  (I'm not justifying the design, just a perspective)